# powershell takes a long time to close connection?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run this powershell script on several remote network servers, but it takes a long time to complete the task and move to the next one.

Here's a basic script that will query a single remote server and return the data I want in a fast manner, but takes a long time to complete the entire script.

```
    Get-EventLog -ComputerName WebServer1 -LogName System -EntryType Error -After ((Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1))
```

I was running it through the Powershell ISE and from the command line in Powershell and both have the same behavior.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you running this command on remote servers?

Comment: Get-Eventlog with the -After parameter will be slow, particularly on large log files, because it reads the entire log file.

Comment: Trevor, I am running it from my network workstation.  The "WebServer1" is the name of the remote server.

Comment: mjolinor, is there any way that I can speed that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the reason: mjolinor outlined that - Get-EventLog parses the whole logfile, and then filters the output to meet your parameters. What we want to do right now is to parse the event log one by one from the newest entries while the condition is true.

```
$i = 0
$EventParser =  do 
{
Get-EventLog -ComputerName Localhost -LogName System -EntryType Error -Newest $i; $i++ 
}
while 
(
(Get-EventLog -ComputerName Localhost -LogName System -EntryType Error -Newest $i | Select -Last 1).TimeWritten -ge ((Get-Date).Date.AddHours(-24))
)
$EventParser|Where-Object { $_.TimeWritten -ge ((Get-Date).Date.AddHours(-24)) } | Sort-Object -Property Index -Descending | Get-Unique -OnType
```

I have measured your command and the loop I have written - here is the output for my machine

For $EventParser:

TotalMilliseconds : 634,6669

For your command (I changed webserver1 to localhost)

TotalSeconds      : 14,3049668

I hope the script above will do the trick to speed up log parsing.

PS.

I have ran into one thing that I couldn't figure out. As you see, I am actually filtering the output twice for, I believe, the same condition (!). If I remove the last-line Where-Object statement, I receive 35 entries for my machine and it lists output even from 4 days ago ?? (Normally I receive 19 entries both from mine and original command). I have had to, to my surprise, re-apply the filter to receive the desired scope. Can you assist with that in a comment or should I post a question on that?

EDIT:

Now the problem doesn't occur. Edit: I have tweaked the code a little bit, I noticed that in some cases it may return duplicated entries.

Best regards,
AlexP

Comment: That is weird that it captures output from 4 days ago.  Any idea on how to get the "Critical" events?

Comment: Does it capture even after applying the second filter ?